# Is there any particular difference between "moving" and "poignant"?

Tags: differences

Both are defined as "making you feel strong feelings of sadness".

Comment: What did your own research indicate ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the alternate definitions of the words. Even when the use case isn't appropriate, they often colour the meaning of the one your looking at.

I would say that "moving" has no implication that the feelings are sad. Unless there has been further context given to imply such emotions, I wouldn't assume it. 'Moving' often evokes a response, e.g. being moved to action. Something 'poignant'; however, may be of intellectual interest in and of itself but not evoke emotions or action.

I see 'moving' as generally positive. If I find a piece of music moving then it may be uplifting. Strong sadness is possible, but only one possible emotion.